# How to catch event errors using chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a typescript library. It exposes the following functions:

```
export declare function setDictionary(_dictionary: object): void;
export declare function getMessage(error: string): any;
export declare function setLoggerLevel(level: string): void;
export declare function on(event: string, handler: IListener): void;
```

Now I would like to test the function getMessage() with Mocha and Chai. I pass a bad input and make it throw (it emits an "error" event plus a *new Error*). This is my code:

```
// Imports and Globals
import * as responseGiver from '../index.js';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';

describe('Public functions', () => {
  describe('getMessage(error : string) : any', () => {
    it('should throw when the dictionary is not set', () => {
      expect( function() { responseGiver.getMessage("A") } ).to.throw(new Error("The dictionary is not set"));
    });
  });
});
```

However, it doesn't work.

```
  Public functions
    getMessage(error : string) : any
error: The dictionary is not set
      1) should throw when the dictionary is not set


  0 passing (14ms)
  1 failing

  1) Public functions getMessage(error : string) : any should throw when the dictionary is not set:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw 'Error: The dictionary is not set'
      at Context.<anonymous> (js-src/test/test.js:17:83)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I've read similar threads on stack overflow, but I still didn't get how to make it work and how chai works in this case. Maybe [this](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-events/) could be helpful, but I don't know how to apply this example to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Basically I didn't compile the tsc files, so I was executing an old version of the code that wasn't working. This is the working code:

```
it('should throw when the dictionary is not set', (done) => {

  responseGiver.on('error',function(){
    done();
  });

  responseGiver.getMessage("A");

});
```